# How do i create a AwesomeWM theme

Tags: archlinux, awesome-wm

i have come across awesomeWM recently and want to create a new theme but i don't know how to create one and how it works i have searched google many times on how to create a awesomewm theme and the results didn't say anything

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that you need to copy the default theme to `~/.config/awesome/theme.lua`, change your config to point to it, then modify it.

But I don't think this is what you really ask. The longer answer is that AwesomeWM is a window manager framework. The config is written in a programming language called Lua. From your config, you can create widgets, bars and fancy things. The "theme" isn't a standalone thing. It is "just" lua code.

The documentation is here
https://awesomewm.org/apidoc/documentation/03-declarative-layout.md.html

The list of theme variables is here:
https://awesomewm.org/apidoc/documentation/06-appearance.md.html

And the getting started guide is here:
https://awesomewm.org/apidoc/documentation/07-my-first-awesome.md.html